# Uniqueness in Permutation and Combination

Tags: algorithm, unique, combinations, permutation

I am trying to create some pseudocode to generate possible outcomes for this scenario:

There is a tournament taking place, where each round all players in the tournament are in a group with other players of different teams.

Given x amount of teams, each team has exactly n amount of players. What are the possible outcomes for groups of size r where you can only have one player of each team AND the player must have not played with any of the other players already in previous rounds.

Example: 4 teams (A-D), 4 players each team, 4 players each grouping.

Possible groupings are:  (correct team constraint)

```
A1, B1, C1, D1
A1, B3, C1, D2
```

But not: (violates same team constraint)

```
A1, A3, C2, D2
B3, C2, D4, B1
```

However, the uniqueness constraint comes into play in this grouping

```
A1, B1, C1, D1
A1, B3, C1, D2
```

While it does follow the constraints of playing with different teams, it has broken the rule of uniqueness of playing with different players. In this case A1 is grouped up twice with C1

At the end of the day the pseudocode should be able to create something like the following

```
Round 1   Round 2   Round 3   Round 4
 a1 b1     a1 d4     a1 c2     a1 c4
 c1 d1     b2 c3     b4 d3     d2 b3

 a2 b2     a2 d1     a2 c3     a2 c1
 c2 d2     b3 c4     b1 d4     d3 b4

 a3 b3     a3 d2     a3 c4     a3 c2
 c3 d3     b4 c1     b2 d1     d4 b1

 a4 b4     a4 d3     a4 c1     a4 c3
 c4 d4     b1 c2     b3 d2     d1 b2
```

In the example you see that in each round no player has been grouped up with another previous player.

Comment: [Social golfer problem?](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You have no idea all the different google searches I went through and didn't see this. 

Thank you, i'll take a look

Comment: Hmm, not quite social golfer.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat it looks pretty similar. Only difference is that in my scenario ALL players must play each day.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat currently trying to see what algorithm they used because from what I read, they can switch how many groupings and amount of players per day.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat anyway you can come explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of players on a team is a prime power (2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, etc.), then here's an algorithm that creates a schedule with the maximum number of rounds, based on a finite affine plane.

We work in the finite field [GF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)(n), where n is the number of players on a team. GF(n) has its own notion of multiplication; when n is a prime, it's multiplication mod n, and when n is higher power of some prime, it's multiplication of univariate polynomials mod some irreducible polynomial of the appropriate degree. Each team is identified by a nonzero element of GF(n); let the set of team identifiers be T. Each team member is identified by a pair in T×GF(n). For each nonzero element r of GF(n), the groups for round r are

```
{{(t, r*t + c) | t in T} | c in GF(n)},
```

where `*` and `+` denote multiplication and addition respectively in GF(n).

[Implementation in Python 3](https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/misc/blob/master/2017-02-02/sg.py)

---

This problem is very closely related to the [Social Golfer Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html). The Social Golfer Problem asks, given n players who each play once a day in g groups of size s (n = g×s), how many days can they be scheduled such that no player plays with any other player more than once?

The algorithms for finding solutions to instances of Social Golfer problems are a patchwork of constraint solvers and mathematical constructions, which together don't address very many cases satisfactorily. If the number of players on a team is equal to the group size, then solutions to this problem can be derived by interpreting the first day's schedule as the team assignments and then using the rest of the schedule. There may be other constructions.

Comment: So the best way to do it would be basing the next rounds/day on the previous/current schedule?

Comment: @KelseyAbreu You can get away with that for small numbers of rounds, but in general, you'll need to schedule the whole thing up front.

Comment: I guess i'm still confused on to how to make sure it's unique.
Could you show me what steps I would do after round 1 of my example?

Comment: I'm still very confused about this. I've tried programming it but I just can't seem to get the answer correct.

More specifically the algorithm for the groups. I just don't understand how to go about programming that.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu It's involved, especially for higher prime powers, if you don't use a big library like SageMath. I'll ping you when I get a chance to do an implementation from scratch.

Comment: Thank you David, I'll be on the lookout for your ping.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu You'll need `gf.py` from the same repo. Python 3 only.

Comment: Haven't played around with Python but the syntax is simple enough to follow. 

Thank you for your time. I'll begin implementing this.

If I need further assistance would you mind if I ping you again? or through some other means?

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Sure, just leave a comment here.

Comment: Something that I noticed is that it doesn't accept the user to input the amount for the grouping. 

Such as in my scenario I wanted groups of 4, even if there's 5+ teams

Comment: @KelseyAbreu That changes things. i'm not sure that this answer will be useful, then.

Comment: Does it make it the problem more difficult? If anything I'm truly only looking for groupings of 4 if that reduces complexity

Comment: also in sg.py, what does the asterisk do in this line

' print(*('{}{}'.format(string.ascii_uppercase '

it's one of the few things preventing me to move it from python 3 to 2.6/2.7

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Prints all of the things generated with spaces between them.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look at some way to moving that around.

but, like I asked, do you think adding the grouping makes the algorithm more difficult even if it's by 4?

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Yeah, it wrecks the mathematical structure.

Comment: Would you mind spending some time on it? Nothing drastic, just want to know if it's still possible.

Also just want to tell you again, thanks for all the effort

Comment: Heya, been able to think about it at all?

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Are you trying to make a schedule where every player plays with every other player not on his team (or close to that), or are the desired schedules much shorter than that?

Comment: The desired schedules are much shorter than that. Given this scenario: 4 teams, 8 players each, the desired schedule may even be just 4 or 5 lineup leaving a lot of players not having played with another. There CAN be cases where the schedule may be for every other player. But I don't think that will ever be the case.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu You could try local search: https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/misc/blob/master/2017-02-07/sg2.py . Banged that out quickly, so there's probably a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: Cool thanks, testing it out right with with params 4,4,4,4. 4 teams, 4 players, 4 rounds, 4 group size. It's just spitting out lots of random 2 digit numbers nonstop. Checking to see why right now

Comment: Took a look and can't really make sense of the output.

Comment: @KelseyAbreu It's the number of conflicts in the current local search state. If it ever hits 0, it will print the schedule.

Comment: Didn't think it would be so random. Even with the small input pool, takes a long time. Thank you